# Can't fire Google Analytics event 50% of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I want to track my signups in Google Analytics to track my Goals. For that, I take new users who sign up to an intermediary page and from there they go to their dashboard. On this intermediary page, I fire a Google analytics event. Here is the code for that page.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
        <script>
            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
                i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                a = s.createElement(o),
                        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                a.async = 1;
                a.src = g;
                m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-YY', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
            ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'registration', eventAction: 'submit', eventLabel: 'newuser', eventValue: 1});
        </script>
        <script src="<path to jquery>/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script> var BASE_URL = "mysite.com"</script>
        //some PHP code here to set a variable MYVAR    
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.replace(BASE_URL + 'MYVAR');
                }, 5);                
            });
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the event fires only about 50% of time. Can you think of a reason why? If it is redirecting before ga(send,..) then any suggestion on making it asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send event with this syntax:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');
```

or this syntax:

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Videos',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign'
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events?hl=it

Or try to put the event code in body instead of head.

Comment: On the same page you can see the syntax I have there as well:

function handleOutboundLinkClicks(event) {
  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventLabel: event.target.href
  });
}

I doubt it is the syntax

Comment: Thanks, I am curious to know why do you think the current code does not work and why putting it in body should work?

Comment: The syntax is different from documentation but works fine so if the pageviews is sent 100% and event 50% or there is an error in JS code i.e. jQuery that blocks the functions or also pageviews are sent at 50%. Just to try if it's not a matter of loading the library at that time.

Comment: Both page views and events are sent 50% of the time. My feeling is that there is something wrong with the document.ready event. I am not sure though and hence wanted someone more knowledgeable to look at it and tell me if any other even like windows.load would make more sense here. If so, why.